# Are local class rules aligned to c++14 return type deduction?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, return-type, auto

While reading this part of C++14 ([a free draft N4141, closest to C++14](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf)):

> 9.8 Local class declarations [class.local]
>
> [..]
>   The name of a local class is local to its enclosing scope. [..]
>
> Declarations in a local class shall not odr-use (3.2) a variable with
>   automatic storage duration from an enclosing scope. [ Example:
>
> ```
> //[..]
> void f() 
> { 
>     static int s ; 
>     int x; 
>     // [..]
>     struct local { 
>        int g() { return x; } // error: odr-use of automatic variable x 
>        int h() { return s; } // OK 
>        // [..]
>    };
> }
> local* p = 0; // error: local not in scope
> ```
>
> —end example ]

I noticed, that, first - I can define `p` with return value auto deduction:

```
auto f()
{
  static int s;
  int x;
  struct local
  {
     int h() { return s; }
  };
  return local{};
}
decltype(f())* p = 0; // OK - ignored, that local is not in scope!
```

Maybe it seems ok, why not to use local type by deducing it from function return value, but - it seems in this way I can access local `s` variable before it is constructed:

```
struct TalkativeInt
{
    TalkativeInt() : value() 
    {
        std::cout << "TalkativeInt()\n";
    }
    TalkativeInt(int value) : value(value) 
    {
        std::cout << "TalkativeInt(" << value << ")\n";
    }

    int value;
};

auto f()
{
  static TalkativeInt s = 7;
  int x;
  struct local
  {
     auto h() { return s.value; }
  };
  return local{};
}
decltype(f())* p = 0;

int main() {
    decltype(f()) l;
    std::cout << l.h();
}
```

Output is just::

```
0
```

But one might expect:

```
TalkativeInt(7)
7
```

Both clang and gcc do not protest in any way, see [demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dP15ThN3TLZSVPiN).

I wonder, maybe such case should be mentioned somehow either in

> 9.8 Local class declarations [class.local]

or in

> 7.1.6.4 auto specifier [dcl.spec.auto]

?

Of course, I feel that reading (and writing) from variable before it is constructed is **bad thing**, but I have not found anything about that in standard - probably, it was not possible before C++14? Or there are some basic rules I just overlooked?

Comment: Ouch, that's nasty. This does look like a loophole, and probably triggers undefined behaviour...

Comment: Hmm. "Local class declarations" only talks about the name not being visible outside. That does not necessarily mean that the type can't be used outside as I see it. I am not quite sure how you would make use of such a function pre-C++11 as you couldn't even declare it with `local` being local. 

But maybe I am just missing the point here.

Comment: §9.8 only says that the _name_ is local. It is not a new thing that you can use an entity without spelling out its name.

Comment: Yes, this is UB, and definitely in Machiavelli territory. [class.cdtor]/1, [basic.life]/6-7.

Comment: @SimonKraemer using local type not in the block of its definition is not my main concern. I am worrying that in this way I can access local static variables before they are constructed

Comment: @T.C. So, are there explicit rules about not using object before it is c-cted? Or this is some kind of "obvious" implicit rule? I can accept answer with citation from standard that disallows what I did in my question.

Comment: @PiotrNycz But that would happen the same (or even easier) if the type wasn't local. I have to correct my previous comment: Pre-C++14 you couldn't even use such a type as return type. So the standard doesn't break any behaviour here. For me you are simply not initializing a static variable (apart from the auto-initialization of static variables). The only problem with your code is that you don't call `f()`.

Comment: @SimonKraemer But I assume it is valid to construct this object `decltype(f()) l;` in main, even if never, ever call `f()`? The only invalid "move" in my example is calling `local::h()` in `main()`, because w/o calling  `f()`- the access to `f()::s` is invalid? At least, I interpreted the Columbo's answer in that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rule for static local variables is [plain and simple](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl#4):

> Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage
>   duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) is performed the
>   first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is
>   considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization.

And accessing an object's members before its construction is disallowed by [[basic.life]/(7.1)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#7).

Comment: I assume that you mean access to `f()::s.value`is wrong in my question, I believe calling `main():l.h()` would be valid if the implementation of this function would not touch `f()::s`?